# Mapped Type Property Name with Different Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Imagine these tree types:

```
type A1 = { m1: boolean };
type A2 = { m2: number };
type B = { m1: string; m2: string };
```

I want to create a new type that must have the same property name but can be of its own type. For example, the union of `A1` and `A2` has the same property name as `B` with different types which is fine.

**Expected Example:**

```
type SafeRetype<T, Z extends T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]?: Z[K]; // This is where I need help
};

type C1 = SafeRetype<B, A1 | A2>; // Expect  { m1?: string; m2?: string };
```

**Expected Failing Example:**

```
type D1 = { z: string };
type Err = SafeRetype<B, D1>; // Expect error because missing "z" does not exist in B (m1|m2)
```

The goal that I am trying to achieve is to be able to have the main type that describes the structure of the properties and then ensuring that the other type has only (all or partially) the properties from the former type with the freedom of changing the type of the properties.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgMwgJQqSAeAKgGigLSggA9gIA7AEwGcosA%20KAXigG8AoKLqAbQGkoAS3JQA1hBAB7BHQC6AfgBcBfrIDc7AL4b26aAEEAjMzZQAtoeUAjSZIA2EOCO27wBgEwnW598vIBXMysIACcoFz0oACEvc0soamAQ4QBzNR9lROTyFPCNSIBhYxZ4JFQ9DCi8IygAHyh9d3p0gHoWqABRYkgAY2AubwslBKTU9LN3YazUvNdIKAARYtMAL0zRnNnIjpCwksQUNDdKvCXmqDbO7og%20ol3JMOCeuH9qaDNBamoZgCIVn6glEkEFo5Ek-RIn36wmiUAAFBZahMAJTsIA)

Comment: How will you determine the types of type `B`? Would you pass a new type into a generic or have it be based on some other type somehow?

Comment: Also, will the number of types you will be "combining" always be two, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: `A1 | A2` does not extend `B`, and the type `A1 | A2` doesn’t really “have the same property names” as `B`... `keyof A|B` is `never`.  So I’m not really following what you’re trying to do exactly.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting `A1 | A2` from except your own example. Did you mean to reply to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `A1 | A2` does not extend `B`

To make it accept only objects that have the same key you can define that the second generic should be an object with the same keys as the first one and any value:

```
type SafeRetype<T, Z extends Record<keyof T, any>> = Partial<T>
```

or

```
type SafeRetype<T, Z extends { [key in keyof T]: any}> = Partial<T>
```

In this case there will be an error when trying to use `D1`

---

Another option would be

```
type SafeRetype<T, Z> = Z extends Record<keyof T, any> ? Partial<T> : never

type Err = SafeRetype<B, D1>;
```

it will not result in an error on the second line, but the value will be `never` and the error will occur whenever you try to assign anything on it

Comment: Thank you Teneff, exactly what I was looking for with the first option :)

Comment: I only modified to return `Partial<Z>` to have the right return type in some cases.

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins but then the value of the property will be based on the first object, not on the second, unlike in your question, but feel free to modify however it fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ambiguous what your exact requirements and use cases are. But it sounds like you just need a combination of the intersection of `A1` and `A2`, but using type property mapping (plus optional params) to override the types @ each key.

```
type A1 = { m1: boolean };
type A2 = { m2: number };

type B = {
    [key in keyof (A1 & A2)]?: string;
}
```

[image: TypeScript intellisense snippet]

Edit: naturally, this could be made into a reusable "generic" quite easily:

```
type A1 = { m1: boolean };
type A2 = { m2: number };

type B<T, N> = {
    [key in keyof T]?: N;
}

type C = B<A1 & A2, string>;
```

Comment: Thanks jered for helping out. I might not have been clear enough but the proposed solution does not block the compilation if the type misses a property. Teneff's solution is what I was looking for. Thanks again for your time.